# Error: Setup version for module 'Namespace_module' is not specified

Tags: magento2, module, setup-upgrade

During module creation I am getting this error (I followed all steps from the tutorial):

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 1889482824

Where the error message is:

> a:4:{i:0;s:57:"Setup version for module 'Namespace_module' is not specified";i:1;s:1410:

The configuration attribute `setup_version` (`<module name="Namespace_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">`) already exist... When I'm trying to run upgrade the module becomes disabled.

Comment: Try to open the log number (`1889482824`) under `var/report` folder  to see more details about your current issue.

Comment: i was tried..module is displaying in status...but fail to open website

Comment: I'm not sure about your current issue. However, the best way to find the cause is to take a look at the log number.

Comment: Did you Set Developer mode.Then  You will get What is the problem in frontend itself

Comment: a:4:{i:0;s:57:"Setup version for module 'Namespace_module' is not specified";i:1;s:1410:

Comment: @Sanj try to run setup upgrade command.

Comment: Yes i did already

Comment: is there really a lower case m in `Namespace_module` (instead of `Namespace_Module`)? This would be wrong and likely the cause of the error.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the setup version for your module. Open the `app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/module.xml` file and change line:

```
<module name="Namespace_Module">
```

to the:

```
<module name="Namespace_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
```

Then run the `setup:upgrade` process from the cli.

Comment: <module name="Namespace_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"> Already exist...when i'm trying to upgrade, module getting disable

Comment: @Sanj Try to find in your module all places where string "module" starts from the lowercase letter, and change it to the uppercase like "Module" and all module files should be Module too.

Comment: tried .. not solved

Comment: @Sanj Can you add the module somewhere on github or bitbucket? It is really hard to say something about your error without a full code :(